# How to use Google Login API with Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, oauth, parse-platform, google-oauth

I want to use "Login with Google" in my Phonegap App. I have read many articles but couldn't find out how it is done. Thanks in Advance. I tried using oAuth2 for "installed Applications" as per this [URL](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp). But then the app users have to manually copy code and paste in my app. 
I am using built.io [Federated Login](http://docs.built.io/guide/users.html#users-federated), if its relevant.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Google has dropped support for the accepted answer above! After April 20th 2017 use of the In-App browser as described by @Deep Mehta will no longer be supported. If you use the accepted answer then it is going to start failing very soon.

Here's Google's post about the change:
https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html

Luckily there's a new plugin that wraps up all the funcitonality that you need to do this:

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus
and on NPM
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-googleplus

Here's an article on how to use it in Ionic 1 and 2 also:
http://blog.ionic.io/google-oauth-changes

Again - DO NOT USE THE ACCEPTED ANSWER! It will fail after April 20 2017.

Comment: Taurus, the latest commit on that plugin was 26 days ago. I would hardly call that abandoned.

Comment: Okay, wrong choice of words. It is not very active, 5 issues in the last 25 days (the last one being mine) and not even of them has one comment.

Comment: What the one you asked 11 hours ago? Sorry nobody is racing to help you on a Saturday.

Comment: The one i asked 11 hours ago, and the other four issues raised within the last 25 days (none of which have any comments, meaning that they haven't been seen by the contributors). And to be honest, i did not notice the saturday thing because where i live, fridays are the weekends.

Comment: Yeah and look at closed and you'll see that other issues have been closed. Look we all try and help out where we can, but this is a small plugin and there will always be open issues. Please don't go around saying a git repo isn't maintained when it is. You are spreading misinformation, especially as the accepted answer on this thread is going to cause a world of hurt to someone who doesn't see my post!

Comment: Only one has been closed, the other 6, asked within the last 25 days, don't even have a single comment. And i know that it must be hard to keep up with all the opened issues when there are nearly 200 open issues, but the contributors should at least comment on the issues so that we know they have been seen, i currently don't know if i should use something else or wait for someone to participate. And if you take a look at my issue, you will see how weird everything is, i don't know what the issue is yet, but, if it is literally because of an alert, then the plugin is highly flawed :)

Comment: But again, it is open source, so, thanks for the plugin i guess.

Comment: Please answer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49662677/phonegap-google-login-plugin-issue-error-4

Comment: Google+ shutdown is not supposed to affect the plugin mentioned in the answer: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/555

Answer (score 31):

add this code in one js file and include in your project. when you want to access google login api on button click call `function callGoogle()` rest will be done by this code. Dont forget to add your client id and Client_Secret keys. Its working fine for me. You need inappbrowser cordova plugin.

```js
var googleapi = {
    authorize: function(options) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
         //Build the OAuth consent page URL
        var authUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?' + $.param({
            client_id: options.client_id,
            redirect_uri: options.redirect_uri,
            response_type: 'code',
            scope: options.scope
        });

        //Open the OAuth consent page in the InAppBrowser
        var authWindow = window.open(authUrl, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');

        //The recommendation is to use the redirect_uri "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
        //which sets the authorization code in the browser's title. However, we can't
        //access the title of the InAppBrowser.
        //
        //Instead, we pass a bogus redirect_uri of "http://localhost", which means the
        //authorization code will get set in the url. We can access the url in the
        //loadstart and loadstop events. So if we bind the loadstart event, we can
        //find the authorization code and close the InAppBrowser after the user
        //has granted us access to their data.
        $(authWindow).on('loadstart', function(e) {
            var url = e.originalEvent.url;
            var code = /\?code=(.+)$/.exec(url);
            var error = /\?error=(.+)$/.exec(url);

            if (code || error) {
                //Always close the browser when match is found
                authWindow.close();
            }

            if (code) {
                //Exchange the authorization code for an access token
                $.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', {
                    code: code[1],
                    client_id: options.client_id,
                    client_secret: options.client_secret,
                    redirect_uri: options.redirect_uri,
                    grant_type: 'authorization_code'
                }).done(function(data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);

                    $("#loginStatus").html('Name: ' + data.given_name);
                }).fail(function(response) {
                    deferred.reject(response.responseJSON);
                });
            } else if (error) {
                //The user denied access to the app
                deferred.reject({
                    error: error[1]
                });
            }
        });

        return deferred.promise();
    }
};
var accessToken;
var UserData = null;

function callGoogle() {

    //  alert('starting');
    googleapi.authorize({
        client_id: 'client_id',
        client_secret: 'Client_Secret',
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost',
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
    }).done(function(data) {
        accessToken = data.access_token;
        // alert(accessToken);
        // $loginStatus.html('Access Token: ' + data.access_token);
        console.log(data.access_token);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        getDataProfile();

    });

}

// This function gets data of user.
function getDataProfile() {
    var term = null;
    //  alert("getting user data="+accessToken);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=' + accessToken,
        type: 'GET',
        data: term,
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(jqXHR, text_status, strError) {},
        success: function(data) {
            var item;

            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            // Save the userprofile data in your localStorage.
            localStorage.gmailLogin = "true";
            localStorage.gmailID = data.id;
            localStorage.gmailEmail = data.email;
            localStorage.gmailFirstName = data.given_name;
            localStorage.gmailLastName = data.family_name;
            localStorage.gmailProfilePicture = data.picture;
            localStorage.gmailGender = data.gender;
        }
    });
    disconnectUser();
}

function disconnectUser() {
    var revokeUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=' + accessToken;

    // Perform an asynchronous GET request.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: revokeUrl,
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(nullResponse) {
            // Do something now that user is disconnected
            // The response is always undefined.
            accessToken = null;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(nullResponse));
            console.log("-----signed out..!!----" + accessToken);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            // Handle the error
            // console.log(e);
            // You could point users to manually disconnect if unsuccessful
            // https://plus.google.com/apps
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Deep, Did same thing. stuck with a window with message "Please copy this code, swith to application and paste it there". Please help !!!.

Comment: Hi Deep, I created client id as Installed Application -> Other. And got redirected URI as urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob . Please let me know is dis the correct way of doing?

Comment: get back to you soon. but if u r in mobile the i think localhost will do. but let me check

Comment: Hi Deep, Found out the solution.. It will works up to android version 17. Not for Kit Kat.

Comment: Has there been any updates with this? Were you able to use OAuth using cordova?

Comment: PXdty : I have not tried since a while. But it should work as its based upon standard way of using Google+ API. If you find any issue let me know will solve it.

Comment: Yes, any workaround for not including the secret in a .js file?

Comment: Add in config file or create system variable.

Comment: I spent lot of time to find the solution but it's by far best and simple. Thanks!

Comment: @MM Tac: I am glad that i was able to help you out. feel free to upvote ;)

Comment: @DeepMehta, what should be the redirect URL? I'm using `http://localhost` for app.

Comment: Yea localhost mostly.

Comment: @DeepMehta, okay thanks. Now I've only one issue that It's asking for permissions every time while we are clicking on sign in button. It should ask for accept permission only first time and then it'll automatically take permission and not ask again. Is there any way while clicking sign in button it'll load pre-fill emailid's from mobile?

Comment: I dont think it will be proper way of doing. i would let user sign in once and refresh token once it gets expired unless he logout from application settings.

Comment: @DeepMehta : I followed your approach in one of my app & it's working fine. Just one issue, I'm getting is... If I've already logged in 3 other gmail accounts with my gmail native app... It's not giving me any option to choose any one from  them.

I've posted about this Stackoverflow at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33481944

Comment: Hello @DeepMehta I have used your code and from google provided code also but the problems after login complete it doesn't coming back to the app from opened popup.  please refer this link I have done same thing but the only problem is it doesn't let me go on my app - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135466/coming-url-doesnt-let-me-go-further-in-cordova-app-after-google-authentication

Comment: @MMTac Did you find any solution for the "accept permission everytime" problem which you mentioned in the comments?

Comment: @RezaRahmati no actually, I don't tried more due to work load so I left that project and moved to another project. Sorry but this is the fact!

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS! If you put your client secret in your app, it doesn't matter whether it is in a config file or hardcoded, PEOPLE WILL ACCESS IT. If someone gains access to your client secret they can act as though they are your app, consume your API limits and generally give you a very bad day.

Comment: I use this for ionic app and getting 403 Error:disallowed_useragent  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40591090/403-error-thats-an-error-error-disallowed-useragent. any solution for this? working good with Android.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40591090/403-error-thats-an-error-error-disallowed-useragent

Comment: @DeepMehta : Please answer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49662677/phonegap-google-login-plugin-issue-error-4

Answer (score 5):

I recommend this cordova plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-googleplus  It's pretty recent but I just added it to my app and it seems to do the trick!

Comment: @Ideluca :  Please answer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49662677/phonegap-google-login-plugin-issue-error-4

Comment: How did you made this plugin work in your app ? Did it worked flawlessly and is it successful ? How did you check whether the user is already logged in on app opening, there ain't any flag mentioned in the doc on github

Answer (score 5):

It's 2019: and Google+ API is shut down.

Google has [an article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova) about how to authenticate using the firebase API.

Answer (score 0):

Another implementation that works well here: https://github.com/valenzia10/PhonegapGoogleLogin

Comment: Hi Jason Washo,I have used above link,Google Login is working fine, need to get the user details.Help me please ASAP.Thanks in Advance

Comment: What details do you need? Usually the scopes define what level of information about the user is accessible.

Comment: I need to get the user Information like Email,Name.Just a basic info of the user.Please help me Jason Washo.