# webView:didFailLoadWithError -1004: Could not connect to the server while connecting google plus in Phonegap ios

Tags: ios, cordova, webview, google-plus

I am getting "webView:didFailLoadWithError -1004: Could not connect to the server" error while accepting google plus authentication before getting profile data. These code was working properly before. Now i am facing these error. No idea why i am not able to connect.Please help me to get rid of these error.Below is my code for  integrating google plus in Phonegap (3.4.0) for ios.

```
 var googleapi = {
        //alert('ready');
        authorize: function(options) {
            var deferred = $.Deferred();

        //Build the OAuth consent page URL
        var authUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?' + $.param({
            client_id: options.client_id,
            redirect_uri: options.redirect_uri,
            response_type: 'code',
            scope: options.scope
        });

        //Open the OAuth consent page in the InAppBrowser
        var authWindow = window.open(authUrl, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=yes');


        $(authWindow).on('  ', function(e) {
            var url = e.originalEvent.url;
            var code = /\?code=(.+)$/.exec(url);
            var error = /\?error=(.+)$/.exec(url);

            if (code || error) {
                //Always close the browser when match is found
                authWindow.close();
            }

            if (code) {
                //Exchange the authorization code for an access token
                $.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', {
                    code: code[1],
                    client_id: options.client_id,
                    client_secret: options.client_secret,
                    redirect_uri: options.redirect_uri,
                    grant_type: 'authorization_code'
                }).done(function(data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);

                    $("#loginStatus").html('Name: ' + data.given_name);
                }).fail(function(response) {
                    deferred.reject(response.responseJSON);
                });
            } else if (error) {
                //The user denied access to the app
                deferred.reject({
                    error: error[1]
                });
            }
        });

        return deferred.promise();
    }
    };



    var accessToken;


    function callGoogle()

    {

    alert('starting');
    googleapi.authorize({
                        client_id: 'CLIENT_ID',
                        client_secret: 'CLIENT_SECRET',
                        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost',
                        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
                        }).done(function(data) {
                                accessToken=data.access_token;
                                alert(accessToken);
                                // $loginStatus.html('Access Token: ' + data.access_token);
                                console.log(data.access_token);

                                getDataProfile();


                                });

}
function getDataProfile()
{
    var term=null;
    //accessToken=null;
    //alert("getting user data="+accessToken);
    $.ajax({
           url:'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token='+accessToken,
           type:'GET',
           data:term,
           dataType:'json',
           error:function(jqXHR,text_status,strError){
           },
           success:function(data)
           {
           var item;
           var dat=data.properties;
           alert("first name="+data.given_name+" last name="+data.family_name+" gender="+data.gender+" email="+data.email);
           console.log(data);

           }
           });

}
```

Comment: even I am having same issue in google plus login in iOS. Kindly post a solution if u get it.

Comment: try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930744/how-to-use-google-login-api-with-cordova-phonegap/23931392#23931392

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this code in one js file and include in your project. when you want to access google login api on button click call `function callGoogle()` rest will be done by this code. Dont forget to add your client id and Client_Secret keys. Its working fine for me. You need inappbrowser cordova plugin.

```
      var googleapi = {
        authorize: function(options) {
            var deferred = $.Deferred();

            //Build the OAuth consent page URL
            var authUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?' + $.param({
                client_id: options.client_id,
                redirect_uri: options.redirect_uri,
                response_type: 'code',
                scope: options.scope

            });

            //Open the OAuth consent page in the InAppBrowser
            var authWindow = window.open(authUrl, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');

            //The recommendation is to use the redirect_uri "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
            //which sets the authorization code in the browser's title. However, we can't
            //access the title of the InAppBrowser.
            //
            //Instead, we pass a bogus redirect_uri of "http://localhost", which means the
            //authorization code will get set in the url. We can access the url in the
            //loadstart and loadstop events. So if we bind the loadstart event, we can
            //find the authorization code and close the InAppBrowser after the user
            //has granted us access to their data.
            $(authWindow).on('loadstart', function(e) {
                var url = e.originalEvent.url;
                var code = /\?code=(.+)$/.exec(url);
                var error = /\?error=(.+)$/.exec(url);

                if (code || error) {
                    //Always close the browser when match is found
                    authWindow.close();
                }

                if (code) {
                    //Exchange the authorization code for an access token
                    $.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', {
                        code: code[1],
                        client_id: options.client_id,
                        client_secret: options.client_secret,
                        redirect_uri: options.redirect_uri,
                        grant_type: 'authorization_code'
                    }).done(function(data) {
                        deferred.resolve(data);

                        $("#loginStatus").html('Name: ' + data.given_name);
                    }).fail(function(response) {
                        deferred.reject(response.responseJSON);
                    });
                } else if (error) {
                    //The user denied access to the app
                    deferred.reject({
                        error: error[1]
                    });
                }
            });

            return deferred.promise();
        }
    };
     var accessToken;
    var UserData=null;

    function callGoogle()
    {

    //  alert('starting');
        googleapi.authorize({
                            client_id: 'client_id',
                            client_secret: 'Client_Secret',
                            redirect_uri: 'http://localhost',
                            scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
                            }).done(function(data) {
                                    accessToken=data.access_token;
                                   // alert(accessToken);
                                    // $loginStatus.html('Access Token: ' + data.access_token);
                                    console.log(data.access_token);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                                    getDataProfile();


                                    });

    }
    // This function gets data of user.
    function getDataProfile()
    {
        var term=null;
      //  alert("getting user data="+accessToken);
        $.ajax({
               url:'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token='+accessToken,
               type:'GET',
               data:term,
               dataType:'json',
               error:function(jqXHR,text_status,strError){
               },
               success:function(data)
               {
               var item;

               console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
// Save the userprofile data in your localStorage.
               localStorage.gmailLogin="true";
               localStorage.gmailID=data.id;
               localStorage.gmailEmail=data.email;
               localStorage.gmailFirstName=data.given_name;
               localStorage.gmailLastName=data.family_name;
               localStorage.gmailProfilePicture=data.picture;
               localStorage.gmailGender=data.gender;
               }
               });
    disconnectUser();
    }
    function disconnectUser() {
      var revokeUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token='+accessToken;

      // Perform an asynchronous GET request.
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: revokeUrl,
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(nullResponse) {
          // Do something now that user is disconnected
          // The response is always undefined.
          accessToken=null;
          console.log(JSON.stringify(nullResponse));
          console.log("-----signed out..!!----"+accessToken);
        },
        error: function(e) {
          // Handle the error
          // console.log(e);
          // You could point users to manually disconnect if unsuccessful
          // https://plus.google.com/apps
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: Man... i looked for a working script since days - many many thanks!

But how do i go on and retrieve the IDs and Propertys from the management api? I would like to get the real time users. But i need the ids and propertys, than i can replace the link in the analytics.api with variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can get access token and user profile data using below code.
Just attach your button event to "onGooglePlusLogin" function and replace client_id and screte_id.

I have tested on iPhone and android devices with phonegap 3.4.0 project.

Cheers!

```
var GoogleLogin = function (id, secret) {
    var clientId = id;
    var clientSecret = secret;
    var accessToken = {};
    var authWindow = null;
    var endSignin = {};

    var openAuthWindow = function () {
        var urlAuth = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?" + "scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&" + "redirect_uri=http://localhost&" + "response_type=code&" + "client_id=" + clientId;


        // Open InAppBrowser to get authorization code
        authWindow = window.open(urlAuth, '_blank', 'location=yes,closebuttoncaption=Done');
        authWindow.addEventListener('loadstart', parseRedirectUrl);

    };

    var parseRedirectUrl = function (e) {
        var url = e.url;
        var thereIsCode = url.indexOf("code=");
        var thereIsError = url.indexOf("error=");

        if (thereIsCode != -1) {
            authWindow.close();
            var toMatch = "code=([^&#]*)";
            var regex = new RegExp(toMatch);
            var result = regex.exec(url);
            if (result != null) {
                var code = result[1];
                exchangeCodeForTokens(code);
            }
        } else if (thereIsError != -1) {
            authWindow.close();
            localStorage["accessToken"] = null;
            endSignin(-1);
        }
    };

    var exchangeCodeForTokens = function (code) {
        var dataQuery = "code=" + code + "&" + "client_id=" + clientId + "&" + "client_secret=" + clientSecret + "&" + "redirect_uri=http://localhost&" + "grant_type=authorization_code";

        requestTokens("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", dataQuery, callBackTokens);
    };

    var callBackTokens = function (resp) {
        var tokensResp = eval('(' + resp + ')');

        if (tokensResp.access_token) {
            localStorage["accessToken"] = tokensResp.access_token;
            localStorage["refreshToken"] = tokensResp.refresh_token;
            localStorage["refreshTime"] = (new Date()).getTime() + 1000 * tokensResp.expires_in;

            accessToken = tokensResp.access_token;
            endSignin(accessToken);
        } else {
            accessToken = null;
            localStorage["accessToken"] = null;
            endSignin(-1);
        }
    };

    var getAccessToken = function (refreshToken) {
        var dataQuery = "client_id=" + clientId + "&" + "client_secret=" + clientSecret + "&" + "refresh_token=" + refreshToken + "&" + "grant_type=refresh_token";

        requestTokens("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", dataQuery, callBackRefreshToken);
    };

    var callBackRefreshToken = function (resp) {
        var tokensResp = eval('(' + resp + ')');

        if (tokensResp.access_token) {
            localStorage["accessToken"] = tokensResp.access_token;
            localStorage["refreshTime"] = (new Date()).getTime() + 1000 * tokensResp.expires_in;

            accessToken = tokensResp.access_token;
            endSignin(accessToken);
        } else {
            accessToken = null;
            localStorage["accessToken"] = null;
            endSignin(-1);
        }
    };

    var requestTokens = function (url, data, callback) {
        var xmlreq = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlreq.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlreq.readyState == 4) {
                callback(xmlreq.responseText);
            }
        };
        xmlreq.open("POST", url, true);
        xmlreq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xmlreq.send(data);
    };

    var isLoggedIn = function (callback) {
        endSignin = callback;
        accessToken = localStorage["accessToken"];

        if (accessToken == "null") {
            accessToken = null;
        }

        if (accessToken !== null && typeof (accessToken) !== 'undefined') {
            var refreshTime = localStorage["refreshTime"];
            var refreshToken = localStorage["refreshToken"];
            var currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();

            if (currentTime < refreshTime) {
                endSignin(accessToken);
            } else {
                getAccessToken(refreshToken);
            }
        } else {
            endSignin(-1);
        }
    };

    var startSignin = function (callbackEnd) {
        endSignin = callbackEnd;
        openAuthWindow();
    };

    var logOut = function () {
        accessToken = null;
        localStorage["accessToken"] = null;
        localStorage["refreshToken"] = null;
    };

    return {
        startSignin: startSignin,
        isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn,
        logOut: logOut
    };
};

function onGooglePlusLogin() {
    var clientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
    var clientSecret = "SECRET_ID";

    // Create login object and initialize it with your app client id and secret
    var gl = new GoogleLogin(clientId, clientSecret);
    gl.startSignin(endLogin);
}

function endLogin(result) {
    if (result === -1) {
        // Login was not successful :(
        alert('Google Login failed!');
    } else {
        // If successful login, use access_token to get profile name
        getProfileData(result);
    }
}

function getProfileData(result) {
    if (result !== null && typeof (result) !== 'undefined') {
        var urlAPI = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=" + result;

        var xmlreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlreq.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlreq.readyState == 4 && xmlreq.status == 200) {
                var response = eval('(' + xmlreq.responseText + ')');
                if (response && response.email && response.id) {
                    // Profile data
                    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                } else {
                    alert("Google Login failed!");
                }
            }
        };
        xmlreq.open("GET", urlAPI, true);
        xmlreq.send();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mayur, I was also suffering from same issue and your answer has solved this. Thanks for the code snippet also.