# Cordova app check if user signed in before closing my app?

Tags: facebook, cordova, google-plus

i'am trying to made cordova application that need user login to (google + or Facebook)

so i show button for sign in to (google+ or Facebook)
but after i close the app and open it again i need the sign in button hide depending on last signed in account

i need to know how i can check if user signed after closing my application?

ie check if user subscribe with data login to my app or no?

Answer (score 1):

You can check this when your application gets loaded in

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use device APIs
    //Create small function which check for is access toke valid or not
    //which returns Boolean true or false
    // Else you can use localStorage.isSignInned and once logged in set it as true.
    if(isSignInned)
    {
        //hide buttons
    }
}
```

You can check facebook javascript api [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript) and google javascript api [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication)
It depends upon how you want your application to work.
I am attaching working sample which i created for [Facebook](https://github.com/deepmehtait/Facebook-Connect-Js) for [GooglePlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930744/how-to-use-google-login-api-with-cordova-phonegap/23931392#23931392)
hope this helps.!

Comment: thank you for response but i ask about "localStorage.isSignInned" it's need a plugin and how can i use it

Comment: second thing :how i can get last access token after closing my app??

Comment: localStorage is by default supported by all browsers. both facebook and google+ api have way of knowing access token. you will find if you check their documentation.