# Creating a new Google Calender Event with cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-calendar-api, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to find a way to create a new google calendar event using cordova/phonegap. I have tried to use [Google's JavaScript Calendar api](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js) for this, but for the OAuth Client ID I must specify an authorized javascript origin, and I am not sure if I can do that with cordova (or if I can, I'm not sure what the URL would be).

If there is a plugin, etc. that could create the event I could use that, if not if you could supply code and instructions for generating the key that would be very helpful.

Thank you all in advanced! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work. http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/google-api-oauth-with-phonegaps-inappbrowser.html

Also a dup of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930744/how-to-use-google-login-api-with-cordova-phonegap)?

Comment: Thanks for the link! I couldn't get the code he supplied in the article to work, but I took the javascript off [his github repo](https://github.com/mdellanoce/google-api-oauth-phonegap/blob/v0.0.1/www/js/index.js) and it worked great!

Comment: @Mulletfingers999 I try with this but I'm not able to insert an event... How did you do this?

Comment: I think it's buried in [this app](https://github.com/whirish/book-me-now) somewhere @piterio