# How to add 'Choose an account' option of google sign-in with hybrid mobile app?

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, google-signin

I've a hybrid mobile app which has built using cordova. Recently, I've included Google Sign-in feature into this. But, one issue which I'm facing  is, even if my native gmail app connected to 3 other gmail accounts... it's not showing me the... "Choose an account" option like other mobile app shows.

EX :

[image]

One of my thought is, maybe because of my app is a hybrid app it's not getting access to native gmail accounts session. That's why, it's not showing me the option.

Am I right? How I can solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you implemented google login in your app. For displaying the choose account dialog box, you have to use [Cordova Google plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus). By using this, it will call the google accounts linked to your android phone and the dialog box like you said will appear.

Hope it will meet your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

this.afAuth.auth .signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider().setCustomParameters({prompt: 'select_account'})) .then((user) => { // your logic code here

```
},(err) => {
  console.log("Error in auh service" + err);
 reject(err);
```

})