# How to add an event to Google Calendar with Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-calendar-api

**Problem**:

I can't add an event using the Google Calendar API with Cordova because they don't allow `file://` origin.

**What I do**:

So, I try to do a request to the URL `POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?key={YOUR_API_KEY}` ([link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#examples)). BUT I have to be logged in... Looking for an answer I came across this link:

- [How to use Google Login API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930744/how-to-use-google-login-api-with-cordova-phonegap)

So, right now I can be logged in. Or at least get an access token. But I still need to insert an event, so I tried again with the previous link (`POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?key={YOUR_API_KEY}`) with the access_token parameter (even with refresh_token). And I always have an error saying I have to be logged... I don't know what I have to do...

**Code**:

```
var CLIENT_ID = '<CLIEND_ID>';
var CLIENT_SECRET = '<CLIENT_SECRET>';
var CALENDAR_API_KEY = '<CALENDAR_API_KEY>';
var SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"];
var evento = {
                titulo: "Nice event",
                detalles: "Details",
                location: "Madrid",
                email: "prueba@test.com"
            };

googleapi.authorize({
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost',
    scope: SCOPES.join(' ')
}).done(function (data) {
    alert('Access Token: ' + data.access_token);
    evento.access_token = data.access_token;
    addEvent(evento);
}).fail(function (data) {
    alert(data.error);
});


function addEvent(evento) {
    var event = {
        calendarId: "primary",
        'summary': evento.titulo,
        'location': evento.location,
        'description': evento.detalles,
        'start': {
            'dateTime': '2016-08-28T09:00:00-07:00',
            'timeZone': '   Europe/Madrid'
        },
        'end': {
            'dateTime': '2016-08-28T17:00:00-07:00',
            'timeZone': '   Europe/Madrid'
        },
        'attendees': [
            {'email': evento.email}
        ],
        'reminders': {
            'useDefault': false,
            'overrides': [
                {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
                {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 60}
            ]
        }
    };

    googleapi.insertEvent(event).done(function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }).fail(function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        alert(JSON.stringify(data.error));
    });
}


// authorize using InAppBrowser
var googleapi = {
    authorize: function (options) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();

        //Build the OAuth consent page URL
        var authUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?' + $.param({
            client_id: options.client_id,
            redirect_uri: options.redirect_uri,
            response_type: 'code',
            scope: options.scope
        });

        //Open the OAuth consent page in the InAppBrowser
        var authWindow = window.open(authUrl, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');
        $(authWindow).on('loadstart', function (e) {
            var url = e.originalEvent.url;
            var code = /\?code=(.+)$/.exec(url);
            var error = /\?error=(.+)$/.exec(url);

            if (code || error) {
                //Always close the browser when match is found
                authWindow.close();
            }

            if (code) {
                //Exchange the authorization code for an access token
                $.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', {
                    code: code[1],
                    client_id: options.client_id,
                    client_secret: options.client_secret,
                    redirect_uri: options.redirect_uri,
                    grant_type: 'authorization_code'
                }).done(function (data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }).fail(function (response) {
                    deferred.reject(response.responseJSON);
                });
            } else if (error) {
                //The user denied access to the app
                deferred.reject({
                    error: error[1]
                });
            }
        });

        return deferred.promise();
    },
    insertEvent: function (options) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        $.post('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' + options.calendarId + '/events?key=' + CALENDAR_API_KEY + '&alt=json', {
            client_id: CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
            access_token: options.access_token,
            scope: SCOPES.join(' '),
            summary: options.titulo,
            location: options.location,
            description: options.detalles,
            start: options.start,
            end: options.end,
            attendees: options.attendees,
            reminders: options.reminders
        }).done(function (data) {
            alert("done");
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).fail(function (response) {
            alert("fail");
            deferred.reject(response.responseJSON);
        });

        return deferred.promise();
    }
};
```

**Recap**:

I have to add an event to the Google Calendar and I can't use the Google Calendar API because they don't allow a `file://` origin. I managed to log on Google but I'm not able to add an event doing a HTTP request to `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?key={YOUR_API_KEY}`. **Anyone knows how to easily add an event to Google Calendar with Cordova?**

**EDIT**:

If I change the headers I get a different error: `"Invalid credentials"`. Right now, I change the `insertEvent` function and I'm doing this:

```
insertEvent: function (options) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' + options.calendarId + '/events?key=' + CALENDAR_API_KEY + '&alt=json',
            data: {
                summary: options.titulo,
                location: options.location,
                description: options.detalles,
                start: options.start,
                end: options.end,
                attendees: options.attendees,
                reminders: options.reminders
            },
            headers: {
                "authorization": "Bearer " + options.access_token
            }

        }).done(function (data) {
            alert("done");
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).fail(function (response) {
            alert("fail");
            deferred.reject(response.responseJSON);
        });
```

Comment: you are not able to made a http request or you are facing issue in login with google only ?

Comment: I'm able to login. But when I call to `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?key={YOUR_API_KEY}` they return an error saying I have to be logged in. So, I need an answer to How to insert an event to Google Calendar with Cordova if I can login but I can't make a call to the previous link without an error about the login...

Comment: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin use this plugin it will help you in creating events anf calendars

Comment: It will help me creating events and calendars in the phone but the question is about Google Calendar