# Google plus sign-in api with phonegap unable to get user information

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins, google-plus

Below code is working with the help of InApp browser plugin but after getting permission from user to get his details, I am not able to show/get his name after browser window closed.
I am getting result - name : undefined

Please help me to get this.Thanks in advance.

Note: I got this code from [How to use Google Login API with Cordova/Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930744/how-to-use-google-login-api-with-cordova-phonegap)

```js
var googleapi = {
    authorize: function(options) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
         //Build the OAuth consent page URL
        var authUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?' + $.param({
            client_id: options.client_id,
            redirect_uri: options.redirect_uri,
            response_type: 'code',
            scope: options.scope
        });

        //Open the OAuth consent page in the InAppBrowser
        var authWindow = window.open(authUrl, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');

        //The recommendation is to use the redirect_uri "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
        //which sets the authorization code in the browser's title. However, we can't
        //access the title of the InAppBrowser.
        //
        //Instead, we pass a bogus redirect_uri of "http://localhost", which means the
        //authorization code will get set in the url. We can access the url in the
        //loadstart and loadstop events. So if we bind the loadstart event, we can
        //find the authorization code and close the InAppBrowser after the user
        //has granted us access to their data.
        $(authWindow).on('loadstart', function(e) {
            var url = e.originalEvent.url;
            var code = /\?code=(.+)$/.exec(url);
            var error = /\?error=(.+)$/.exec(url);

            if (code || error) {
                //Always close the browser when match is found
                authWindow.close();
            }

            if (code) {
                //Exchange the authorization code for an access token
                $.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', {
                    code: code[1],
                    client_id: options.client_id,
                    client_secret: options.client_secret,
                    redirect_uri: options.redirect_uri,
                    grant_type: 'authorization_code'
                }).done(function(data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);

                    $("#loginStatus").html('Name: ' + data.given_name);
                }).fail(function(response) {
                    deferred.reject(response.responseJSON);
                });
            } else if (error) {
                //The user denied access to the app
                deferred.reject({
                    error: error[1]
                });
            }
        });

        return deferred.promise();
    }
};
var accessToken;
var UserData = null;

function callGoogle() {

    //  alert('starting');
    googleapi.authorize({
        client_id: 'Myclientid',
        client_secret: 'secret id',
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost',
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
    }).done(function(data) {
        accessToken = data.access_token;
        // alert(accessToken);
        // $loginStatus.html('Access Token: ' + data.access_token);
        console.log(data.access_token);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        getDataProfile();

    });

}

// This function gets data of user.
function getDataProfile() {
    var term = null;
    //  alert("getting user data="+accessToken);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=' + accessToken,
        type: 'GET',
        data: term,
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(jqXHR, text_status, strError) {},
        success: function(data) {
            var item;

            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            // Save the userprofile data in your localStorage.
            localStorage.gmailLogin = "true";
            localStorage.gmailID = data.id;
            localStorage.gmailEmail = data.email;
            localStorage.gmailFirstName = data.given_name;
            localStorage.gmailLastName = data.family_name;
            localStorage.gmailProfilePicture = data.picture;
            localStorage.gmailGender = data.gender;
        }
    });
    disconnectUser();
}

function disconnectUser() {
    var revokeUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=' + accessToken;

    // Perform an asynchronous GET request.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: revokeUrl,
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(nullResponse) {
            // Do something now that user is disconnected
            // The response is always undefined.
            accessToken = null;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(nullResponse));
            console.log("-----signed out..!!----" + accessToken);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            // Handle the error
            // console.log(e);
            // You could point users to manually disconnect if unsuccessful
            // https://plus.google.com/apps
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<div data-role="page">

        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
           <p onclick="callGoogle();">Google Login</p>
            <p><span id="loginStatus"></span></p>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer Text</h1>
        </div>

    </div>
```