# How to implement Google Login in Cordova/Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, phonegap, google-oauth

I need some help regarding Google OAuth2.
I want to implement Google login in my hybrid application but am facing some problems.

If anyone has a demo application/solution please help,that would be great help for me.

Please
Thanks

Comment: do you try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930744/how-to-use-google-login-api-with-cordova-phonegap

Comment: yes but getting error on "var deferred = $.Deferred();"

Comment: please tell us what you have tried and then we can help you figure out where you are stuck. But stackoverflow.com is not a place for finding code to copy

Comment: You can try this: http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/google-api-oauth-with-phonegaps-inappbrowser.html

Comment: Thanks for the response .. i have tried  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930744/how-to-use-google-login-api-with-cordova-phonegap

and https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B1_3YEa53h-EMTV6Q2x1Ti1hams