# Phonegap Google Login Plugin issue error : 4

Tags: javascript, cordova, oauth, google-oauth, phonegap

I am using this plugin : https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus

I am trying to check as soon as my app opens if the user is already logged in or not.  However i am getting an error **error : 4**.

Also which variable I need to use to check that user is already logged in or not does this code returns something for this?

```
window.plugins.googleplus.trySilentLogin({

        'scopes': '',
        'offline': true

    },
    function(obj) {

        alert(JSON.stringify(obj));

        alert('YES GOOGLE LOGGED IN');

    },
    function(msg) {

        //outputs error : 4 
        alert('GOOGLE LOGIN error: ' + msg);

    }
);
```

**UPDATE :**

However, the

> window.plugins.googleplus.login

method works without any issue but the trySilentLogin gives this error code : 4.

**UPDATE 2 :**

In my app just for testing, first I called login method it returned me the token, then after that i called the trySilentLogin, it also  returned me the token, but when i do vice-versa, i.e. first time i call trysilentLogin without calling login method then it says error : 4 and then in next call i called the login method which also gave error : 4

Comment: @DalmTo : Please see my update also

Comment: @DalmTo : if you could provide any solution :)

Comment: @CBroe : Could you please suggest some insights to this ?

Comment: You don't have any scopes set or any API key. The function has the exact same implementation as the login function

Comment: @NicoWesterdale : But how do I check that the user is already logged in via Google ? Is there any variable like loginStatus etc. in this plugin ?

Comment: @NicoWesterdale : In my app just for testing, first I called login method it returned me the token, then after that i called the trySilentLogin it also  returned me the token, but when i do vice-versa, i.e. first time i call trysilentLogin without calling login method then it says error : 4 and then login method also gave error : 4, please see my update 2

Comment: You should post this in the github issues. The developer is very active

Comment: @NicoWesterdale : Yeah I have already done that but it doesn't seems that the developer is active as its been 2 days there ain't any reply